# LINQ: transparent record inserting and updating

Tags: c#, linq

What is the custom wen the record inserting/updating is carried out?

I have this Log table in the MS SQL server database, and a C# class (example is simplified)

```
[Table(Name = "dbo.Sys_Log")]
public class Sys_Log
{
    // Read-only, db-generated primary key ID
    private int _logID;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Storage="_logID", IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int logID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._logID;
        }
    }

    // Read-only db-generated datetime field
    private System.DateTime _logTime;
    [Column(Storage="_logTime", IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public System.DateTime logTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this._logTime;
        }
    }

    // Read-write string field
    private string _logEvent;
    [Column(Storage="_logEvent")]
    public string logEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return this._logEvent;
        }
        set
        {
            this._logEvent = value;
        }
    }

    public Sys_Log() {}

    public Sys_Log(string logEvent)
    {
        this.logEvent = logEvent;
    }
}
```

And this is how I add a log entry:

```
Table<Sys_Log> linqLog = db.GetTable<Sys_Log>();
Sys_Log l = new Sys_Log("event");
linqLog.InsertOnSubmit(l);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I am not particularly happy about this code. I'd like something like this instead:

```
Sys_Log.Log("event");
```

I have idea how this can be achieved, but I'd like to know if I am following the LINQ philosophy. With this code added to the Sys_Log class

```
private static DataContext db;
public static void Connect(DataContext db)
{
    Sys_Log.db = db;
}
public static void Log(string logEvent)
{
    Table<Sys_Log> linqLog = db.GetTable<Sys_Log>();
    Sys_Log l = new Sys_Log(logEvent);
    linqLog.InsertOnSubmit(l);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I can now do this:

```
Sys_Log.Connect(db); // Only once, at init
Sys_Log.Log("event1");
Sys_Log.Log("event2");
```

Are there any pitfalls, apart from the fact that the database is updated several times, that could be considered ineffective?

************** Update ******************

Following the advice of @usr not to reuse the DataContext object, I have made these changes to the Sys_Log class:

```
private static SqlConnection db;
public static void Connect(SqlConnection db)
{
    Sys_Log.db = db;
}
public static void Log(string logEvent)
{
    DataContext ctx = new DataContext(db);
    ctx.CommandTimeout = 240;

    Table<Sys_Log> linqLog = ctx.GetTable<Sys_Log>();
    Sys_Log l = new Sys_Log(logEvent);
    linqLog.InsertOnSubmit(l);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fresh data context each time. Reusing the same context has to catastrophic consequences:

1. No entity memory is ever released
2. When an invalid entity enters the context (due to a bug) it is stuck and will forever prevent SubmitChanges from succeeding. The application will never recover

Also note, that L2S is deprecated and EF has superseded it.

You can share a SqlConnection and use it long-term if you really want. That requires, through, that you deal with broken connections. Thanks to connection pooling there are little performance incentives to do this.

It usually is the easiest and most clear way to use throw-away connections. Inject a factory, for example:

```
Func<SqlConnection> myFactory = () => new SqlConnection(myConnStr);
```

That's all there is to it. Use it, as always, with `using`:

```
using(var conn = myFactory()) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have incorporated your suggestion in my post. I'll take note of your remark about EF superseding L2S, however since the rest of the project is using L2S, at this moment I will stick to L2S for now.

Comment: That's reasonable. I have 100kLOC stuck on L2S right now because EF still is not up to par when it comes to LINQ translation.

Comment: Oh, looking at that code, you should not be reusing the SqlConnection. It can break as well rendering the app permanently down. Inject a connection factory, maybe a `Func<SqlConn>`.

Comment: Could you, please, point me to some reference that shows how such a connection factory is implemented? I am a bit at loss how paranoid at sharing a SqlConnection object I should be. Instantiating for every transaction and closing after it feels like overkill. Please add that to your answer so that I can accept it in order to give this topic peace.

Comment: I've made some edits. This is a really simple way to create a factory.